# Cant understand the game tree for Quarto game

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am going to implement quarto game in which each opponent choose the next step for another opponent but I am having trouble to draw min max node and understand which node is max and which is min? the only thing that came to my mind is this :

[image]

But I am pretty sure that something is wrong with that?

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, I'm assuming that at the top node P1 is choosing a piece for P2 to place, at the second node P2 is placing the piece, at the third node P2 is choosing a piece for P1 to place, and then at four P1 is placing that piece and so on.

I can see why you might think that you're doing something wrong, because this is not the way that minimax is conventionally set up, but this seems like a logical way to apply it for quarto. You are correctly assigning min and  max turns and such, so I don't see anything inherently wrong with this setup. Keeping track of the choosing vs. placing nodes for the purposes of the evaluation function could potentially get tricky, but I think it should be doable. Have you encountered any obstacles with doing it this way? If not, I'd say to give it a shot. It's an interesting twist on standard minimax.

Comment: Thanks for answering, what about the huristic function,Should I have two huristic for that?

Comment: That's an interesting question, and I think it would depend a lot on the heuristic function that you come up with. I'm having a hard time coming up with one, because there is so little differentiation in a given board set-up between the two players. You can evaluate if someone has won on a given board, but just looking at a board and saying who has the advantage seems pretty hard. If you can think of heuristic functions for each case, that would probably be a good option, since it would most likely be even harder to make one that could work for either type of node.